# When Kafka Consumer subscribe the event, it show Timed out 1 in-flight

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, subscribe, consumer, confluent-platform

This script is the method to subscribe event from Kafka.

```
using Confluent.Kafka;
using Confluent.Kafka.Serialization;
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string brokerList = "broker";
    var topics = new List<string>() { "topicName" };
    var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "group.id", "ConsumerGroup" },
        { "bootstrap.servers", brokerList },
        { "auto.offset.reset", "earliest" },
        { "enable.auto.commit", false }
    };

    using (var consumer = new Consumer<string, string>(config, new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8), new StringDeserializer(Encoding.UTF8)))
    {
        consumer.OnMessage += (obj, msg) =>
        {
            ...
        };

        consumer.Subscribe(topics);

        while (true)
        {
            consumer.Poll(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));
        }
    }
}
```

When I trace the code in Debug mode, the order of subscribing event is:

1. `consumer.Subscribe(topics)`
2. `consumer.Poll(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));`
3. `consumer.OnMessage += (obj, msg) =>`

Before getting the new event (go to `consumer.OnMessage`), it spent a little time to poll (in `consumer.Poll`) and print some information on console window.

As follow:

```
4|2018-12-12 10:41:53.381|rdkafka#consumer-1|REQTMOUT| [thrd:broker/bootstrap]: broker/bootstrap: Timed out 1 in-flight, 0 retry-queued, 0 out-queue, 0 partially-sent requests
```

In my original thoughts, it use `consumer.Subscribe(topics)` to connect broker and use `consumer.Poll` to consume the new event.

But it seems that the `consumer.Poll` includes connecting to broker and consuming the new event.

### My questions are:

1. Which function can connect to broker?  `consumer.Subscribe` or
   `consumer.Poll` or?
2. Why `consumer.Poll` print the information on console window? And it seems that having some error (**Timed out 1 in-flight**).

Answer (score 0):

About your first question.

> Which function can connect to broker?  consumer.Subscribe or consumer.Poll or?

`consumer.Subscribe` connect to broker and `consumer.Poll` consume messages.

And about the second one.

> Why consumer.Poll print the information on console window? And it seems that having some error (Timed out 1 in-flight).

Confluent.Kafka has released in a new major version in [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet). If you have any problem with previous versions you can use the recommended version. based on the GitHub repository:

> It has more features, is considerably improved and is more performant than 0.11.x releases